# Is using my iPod touch always plugged in an OK thing to do?

Tags: ipod-touch, battery, audio

I recently added an iPod interface to my Accord: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001JT5G4G/ref=oh_o02_s00_i00_details](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001JT5G4G)

It has two connections: the regular Apple 30-pin iPod dock cable which plays back and charges and then an AUX 3.5 mm headphone connector.

I get the best sound when connected to the Apple connector, but it is also charging it at the same time. I really don't use it much outside of my commute to work ~1 hr. per day, so is it bad for the battery to be plugged in all the time? The car interface won't overcharge it; it stops when full. I just didn't know if I needed to actually use the Li-ion battery in the iPod to keep it useful when I do need to take it unplugged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll probably be fine.

1. If it's always plugged in, you won't notice any battery decay because the device will always be charged (or pulling off mains power) when you need it.
2. Any battery decay will probably take long enough that it'll be time to buy a new iPod by the time you notice anything severe.

The easiest way to mitigate this I can think of is to unplug the device over the weekend, remove it from the car, and let it discharge on its own. Then, on Monday, plug it back in and go. This has the added advantage that it's not subjected to the temperature extremes the interior of a car can see over a period of extended non-use.